# AEM Workflow - set values in a custom dialog from with data gathered in previous process step

Tags: adobe, aem

My overall goal is: launch a process step that runs a java class that gathers a list, then in the next workflow step this list needs to be displayed inside a custom dialog.

This is what i have so far:

- Java Class that uses the metadata put and saves the list into the metadata
- The custom dialog made that uses a textarea which is where this list needs to be displayed
- Another Java class that retrieves gets the list from the metadata

The issue i have now is: how can i get the list from the metadata to show in my custom dialog?

I been searching for ages and seems like no one has ever done it before

Comment: Can you please share a package and sourcecode of what you have done so far? or maybe a simpler version? I believe I may have a way to do what you're asking, but I'd like to test it first.

Comment: I dont have anything special written for now, this is a proof of concept we just want to see if its possible.
2 java files, one is using put `workItem.getWorkflowData().getMetaDataMap().put("referencingList", "testValueForDialog");`
and the other one is using get:
`String value = workItem.getWorkflowData().getMetaDataMap().get("referencingList", java.lang.String.class);`

Comment: It should be possible, The way granite UI widgets get populated for components is actually by obtaining the values from a pre-populated request attribute, namely "granite.ui.form.values". So basically, if you set all your values in a value map and set that to the request attribute "granite.ui.form.values" before any granite widget is processed, you'll effectively prepopulate the dialog. If you can produce a skeleton workflow, I can possibly get it to a working shape.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4UUnxM14WA0XzZES05CWkVsOUk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Please note: this answer was tested and developed on AEM 6.3**

Here is a simple granite UI widget to display ALL of the key/value pair in the current workflow `MetaDataMap` (including ones set in previous workflow steps)

**First, let's create the workflow dialog:**

create a component under apps: `/apps/so-wf-test/wf-components/wf-metadata`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" 
    componentGroup=".hidden"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="A dummy component needed for the dialog"
    sling:resourceSuperType="foundation/components/parbase"/>
```

Create the dialog: `/apps/so-wf-test/wf-components/wf-metadata/cq:dialog`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Display all workflow metadata"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <columns
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <metadataList
                       jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                       sling:resourceType="/apps/so-wf-test/wf-granite-widgets/wf-metadata-list"/>
                </items>
            </columns>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

> note that above dialog includes a custom granite widget to display the metdata list: `<metadataList jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="/apps/so-wf-test/wf-granite-widgets/wf-metadata-list"/>`

**Now The granite widget JSP**

create sling folder: `/apps/so-wf-test/wf-granite-widgets/wf-metadata-list`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:Folder"/>
```

Inside create `wf-metadata-list.jsp`:

> This can be done via Use API or sling models with HTL Or via a servlet. I went with JSP for fast solution for the purposes of this answer.

```jsp
<%@include file="/libs/granite/ui/global.jsp"%><%
%><%@page import="com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession,
                  com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.WorkItem,
                  com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.WorkflowData,
                  com.adobe.granite.workflow.metadata.MetaDataMap,
                  org.slf4j.Logger,
                  org.slf4j.LoggerFactory"%>
<%
    // get a logger
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    // when a workflow dialog is requested, the workitem id is passed as an attribute "item"
    String workitemId = request.getParameter("item");

    // get workflow session
    WorkflowSession wfSession = resourceResolver.adaptTo(WorkflowSession.class);

    // get the current workitem
    WorkItem workitem = wfSession.getWorkItem(workitemId);

    // get workflow data
    WorkflowData workflowData = workitem.getWorkflowData();

    // get metadata map 
    MetaDataMap metaDataMap = workflowData.getMetaDataMap();

%>
    <h1>MetaDataMap Values:</h1>
<ul>
    <% 
       // Iterate over metaDataMap and print all key/val pairs to a list item
       for (Object entry : metaDataMap.keySet())
       {
          Object objVal = metaDataMap.get(entry);
          String val =  objVal == null ? "" : objVal.toString();
          
          %>
        <li><h3><%=entry%>:  <%=val%></h3></li>
          <%
       }
    %>
</ul>
```

** Now just wire the dialog into your dialog workflow step **
using the path `/apps/so-wf-test/dialogs/wf-dialog/cq:dialog"`

Once the workflow reaches the dialog step, you'll see the list of metadata items.

**Example:**

I have created a working example that has the simple steps

- step 1: add `"someKey"="SOME VALUE"` to MetaDataMap
- step 2: get `"someKey"` and print it
- step 3: dialog step pointing to dialog above

Here is a sceenshot of the dialog:

[image: workflow dialog]

Here is a package you can download and install

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-_At1NXpw0EOFNaUVdYcGVHNnM/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-a_8b0SoC25dxwTTCHw2vRg

Comment: Hey @Ahmed, do you know how to set a custom object (an Asset object) in the `MetaDataMap`? because I can't do that, I just was able to include strings.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy this solution explicitly returns strings for the dropdown. in your case, I'd add the asset path to a dropdown item value, then resolve that asset from path in the next wf step.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam my solution is just to show the non published Assets, that's why I'm seting the asset in a list in the first workflow step and in the second I want to show those images in the custom dialog.. there's no way to send a custom object in that MetaDataMap?

Comment: I might be missing your point... but if you just want to show the asset image, then just add the asset path to the MetaDataMap. Then resolve that asset from path and add a `<img src="path/to/my/asset/image"/>` to the markup to show that asset. Also, have you tried a simple POJO instead of Asset?

Comment: The difficulty in AEM in referencing data that was introduced in a previous workflow step is rage-inducing.